# Shortcuts in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keyboard(mouse) shortcut in eclipse to check:

1. From which class a particular method has been called(i.e. navigating from called class to calling class).
2. which class(es) has extended a particular class(i.e. navigating from parent class to child class).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here i have some navigation and code information shortcut for eclipse

```
Ctrl+Alt+h   Open Call Hierarchy
Ctrl+u       Find occurrences of expression in current file
Ctrl+move    over method    Open Declaration or Implementation
Ctrl+o       Show code outline / structure
F2           Open class, method, or variable information (tooltip text)
F3           Open Declaration: Jump to Declaration of selected class, method, or parameter
F4           Open Type Hierarchy window for selected item
Ctrl+t       Show / open Quick Type Hierarchy for selected item
Ctrl+Shift+t Open Type in Hierarchy
```

and for more short cut go [HERE](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html)

Answer (score 3):

Select a class /method and press `ctrl+alt+h` to find where all it has been used.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Open Call Hierarchy` option-

[image]

2] Use `Open Type Hierarchy`(F4) for class references . Example

```
public class Super {

}

class Sub1 extends Super{

}

class Sub2 extends Super{

}
```

Output -

[image]